# How to replace keys (key labels) in a dictionary from a list of tokens

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace, key

I have a dictionary

`dict = {'a': 'cat', 'b':'dog'}`

and I want to replace the keys in the dict
with new keys (or key labels) from a list `['c', 'd']` so that I get (the same)

`dict = {'c': 'cat', 'd':'dog'}`. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the relation between the dictionary and the list?

Comment: How do we know that `a` becomes `c` and `b` becomes `d` and not possibly `a` becomes `d`. Dicts are not ordered.

Comment: That the number of letters, as new key names, are equal to the number of keys in the dict. So that the dict with keys 'a' and 'b' are replaced by new key names 'c' and 'd' in the list.

Comment: I'm strictly looking to replace/rename "a" to "c", "b" to "d" in the dict where "c" and" "d" are from a list. The sequence of "c" and "d" are generated in another function

Comment: @user1749431 And here is the problem. Why "a" to "c" and not "b" to "c". Once again, the keys aren't ordered.

Comment: Hyperboreus, the list with the replacement key names ['c', 'd'], is ordered but  "a" and "b" are ordered through other functions so I only need to replace the names.

Comment: Then you can create a mapping dictionary as @thefourtheye suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the relation between the old keys and their replacements, in another dictionary, like this. Here, `mapping` is the dictionary which maps the old keys with the new keys.

```
d, mapping = {'a': 'cat', 'b':'dog'}, {"a":"c", "b":"d"}
print {mapping[k]:v for k, v in d.items()}
```

**Output**

```
{'c': 'cat', 'd': 'dog'}
```

Comment: Probably right given the wording of the question, but I suspect the OP isn't acknowledging that dicts are not ordered.

Comment: Lol, I just typed exactely the same code on my console in order to post it. Letter, by letter.

Answer (score 0):

As already has been pointed out, a dictionary is not ordered. So if you want to replace your keys with values from a list (which is ordered), you will need to specify how the keys of your dict are ordered. Something along these lines:

```
def replaceKeys (d, newKeys, sort):
    return {newKeys[idx]: v for idx, (_, v)
        in enumerate(sorted(d.items(), key = lambda kv: sort(kv[0])))}

d = {'cat': 'gato', 'dog': 'chucho', 'mule': 'mula'}
d2 = replaceKeys(d, ['a', 'b', 'c'], lambda oldKey: oldKey) #sort alphabetically
print(d2)
d2 = replaceKeys(d, ['a', 'b', 'c'], lambda oldKey: -len(oldKey)) #sort by length ascending
print(d2)
d2 = replaceKeys(d, ['a', 'b', 'c'], lambda oldKey: oldKey[2]) #sort by third letter
print(d2)
```